# How to update/populate multiple input fields with ajax callback?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The code that I have below works. I just need to populate the input fields to update the values once the ajax call is completed. However, I don't know the ajax success function to callback the php variable ($first, $last, etc.) to populate those input fields. Thanks in advance!

**HTML:**

```
<div class="field-wrap">
  <input id="first" class="form-control" name="first" value="<?php echo $first ?>"/>
  <input id="last" class="form-control" name="last" value="<?php echo $last ?>"/>
  <input id="title" class="form-control" name="title" value="<?php echo $title ?>"/>
  <input id="user_input" class="form-control" name="user_input" type="text"/>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#user_input').on('change',function(){
      var input_user = $(this).val();
      if(input_user){
        $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:'ajax.php',
          data:{user_input:user_input},
          success: function(){
          ???WHAT DO I NEED TO PUT HERE TO POPULATE THE INPUT FIELDS WITH DATA
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

PHP:

```
$user_input = $_POST['user_input'];
$query_sql = $DB_CON_A->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_account WHERE account=:user_input");
$query_sql->bindValue(':user_input', $user_input, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_sql->execute();
$user = $query_sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$first = $user['first_name'];
$last = $user['last_name'];
$title = $user['title'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your php, you will probably just want to `echo` a `json` object/array:

```
die(json_encode($user));
```

In your ajax success, just parse the encoded `json` string:

```
success: function(response){
    var data = JSON.parse(response);
    $('#first').val(data.first_name);
    $('#last').val(data.last_name);
    $('#title').val(data.title);
}
```

I would probably change your input field names to match the returned columns from the database (like you have for `title`), that way you can use `$.each()` and easily auto-poulate any amount of matching input names without having to specifically use an `id`attribute on your form fields. You could use `$('input[name='+key+']').val(value);` in a loop *IF* the column names match the form names.

Also, make sure you are sending back html-safe strings. If user has saved `<script>doSomething(nasty)</script>` or similar, you could be putting malicious code into your html. I would maybe use `htmlspecialchars($value,ENT_QUOTES)` for your values on the return. Depends what is in your database for `first_name`, `last_name`, and `title`.

Comment: Thanks. Will try. Should I use echo(json_encode($user)) or die(json_encode($user)) ?

Comment: I would use `die()` so there is no output after that. It may malform the json back to the ajax. It's safer to `die()`.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Will make adjustment to the code accordingly. BTW, if I want to pass the variables/values to angularjs, how should I do it?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with angularjs, so I can't help you there!! Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your `ajax.php` should return true or false
if return true, it will pass to `ajax.success`,
otherwise, it will pass to `ajax.error`

In your `ajax.success`, you should doing something that response(Submission Successful)
maybe alert, maybe redirect to other page.
Here is a example:

```
success: function(){
   alert('Submission Successful!! ');
}
```